# Recover media after factory reset (One Plus One)

Tags: cyanogenmod, internal-storage, factory-reset, data-recovery, oneplus-one

I've recently done a factory reset on my OPO. I though I didn't need anything on it anymore but now I do actually need some pictures who were on it before the reset.

I'm trying to get those pictures back. However, recovery programs do not work because the OPO does not get recognized as a USB mass storage device, since it only has internal storage and there isn't any SD card to find.

Is there anyone with similar problems or does anyone know how to solve this?

Android version 4.4.4

CyanogenMod version 11.0-XNPH38R

Answer (score 1):

You can try [DiskDigger undelete (root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.defianttech.diskdigger) or [Undeleter Recover Files & Data](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete) app.
I had more success with DiskDigger though.